# Mail.app shows empty Gmail labels, but they're not empty in Gmail

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, imap

This used to work, but at some point it stopped.  I have labels defined in Gmail. In Mail.app they show up as folders on the left side, like:

[image]

That image shows the `apartments` label. The problem is that Mail.app thinks there are 0 message in `apartments`, but if I go to Gmail I see 27 messages.

The "Show in IMAP" checkbox is checked in Gmail settings.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, never did.

Comment: I found a few tips around the internet regarding label and rebuilding did you try all those methods?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, under Mailbox there is a Synchronise option. This worked for me on Sierra.